# Reverse Geocode - minresults not working for Mode type retrieveAreas

Tags: api, here-api

When calling the API reverse.here.com with mode retrieveAreas and minsresults set to 1 for a location that is just off the coast of UK I don't get any results.  However when I use the retrieveAddresses I get addresses,  I need areas with the distance and direction.

This is the request I make https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?minresults=1&prox=51.938698%2C%201.435819&mode=retrieveAreas&gen=9&app_id={MYAPPID}&app_code={MYAPPCODE}

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify with the mode=retrieveAddresses the geocoder will search endlessly until minimum one address is found but this is not for retrieve areas.That is the reason without entering the radius it is giving you the addresses in response.

To get the successful response in case of mode=retriveAreas you have to enter the radius in meter as below request.

```
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?
minresults=1&prox=51.9387,1.43582,10000&mode=retrieveAreas&gen=9
&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was using a proximity of 1000 (1km) obviously that was too small.
However the documentation says:"minresults 
xs:int
Indicates that the service is to ignore the specified radius until minResults results are found. The default is 0. Supported for Reverse Geocode mode=retrieveAreas and mode=retrieveAddresses."